# Django REST Framework and FileField absolute url

Tags: python, django, url, filefield

I've defined a simple Django app that includes the following model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='media', null=True)
```

(Technically yes, that could have been an ImageField.)

In a template, it's easy enough to include the MEDIA_URL value (duly coded in settings.py) as a prefix to the thumbnail URL.  The following works fine:

```
<div id="thumbnail"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ current_project.thumbnail }}" alt="thumbnail" width="400" height="300" border="0" /></div>
```

Using DRF, I've defined a HyperlinkedModelSerializer descendant called ProjectSerializer:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ( 'id' ,'url', 'name', 'thumbnail')
```

And I've defined a very straightforward ModelViewSet descendant:

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

A sample of the resulting JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/projects/1/", 
    "name": "Institutional", 
    "thumbnail": "media/institutional_thumb_1.jpg"
}
```

I have not yet been able to figure out how to provide a thumbnail field that includes the full url to the image in my project's JSON representation.

I would think that I would need to create a custom field in the ProjectSerializer, but have not been successful.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield)

Example (untested):

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_thumbnail_url')

    def get_thumbnail_url(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(obj.thumbnail_url)
```

The request must available to the serializer, so it can build the full absolute URL for you.  One way is to explicitly pass it in when the serializer is created, similar to this:

```
serializer = MySerializer(account, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: How do you modify this to make it work with multiple images? Say he had  a class called Preview that has a ForeignKey relation to Project. So Project has a preview_set and he wanted to achieve the same thing for each preview he had for the project. How do you achieve the same thing for each preview?

Comment: You don't need to pass the ``request``. It is available already in ``self.context['view'].request``.

Comment: The problem with this is that ```SerializerMethodField``` is read-only

Comment: In my case, just setting `context={'request': request}` when instantiating a serializer was enough to get the absolute URL. No need for `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: as @SerranoPereira said, for me it worked only with the `context`

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `obj.thumbnail.url`, instead of `self.thumbnail_url`

Comment: This won't work if `MEDIA_URL` has a different domain.

Comment: This answer made me realize that using `context={'request': request}` as serializer parameter, the file field will return the absolute URL if it's accessed from another domain.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks, shavenwarthog.  Your example and documentation reference helped enormously.  My implementation is slightly different, but very close to what you posted:

```
from SomeProject import settings

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    thumbnail_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_thumbnail_url')

    def get_thumbnail_url(self, obj):
        return '%s%s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL, obj.thumbnail)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'thumbnail_url')
```

Comment: You don't need to import setting.MEDIA_URL. Simply return: obj.thumbnail.url

Answer (score 7):

To get the url of a file which uses FileField you can just call the url attribute of the FieldFile (this is the file instance not the field), it use the Storage class to determine the url for this file. It's very straightforward if you are using a external storage like Amazon S3 or if your storage changes.

The get_thumbnail_url would be like this.

```
def get_thumbnail_url(self, obj):
    return obj.thumbnail.url
```

You can also use it in the template this way:

```
{{ current_project.thumbnail.url }}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found it annoying to write the same code for a serialized method field.
If you have set correctly the `MEDIA_ROOT` to your S3 bucket URL, you can add a field to the serializer like:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logo_url = serializers.URLField(read_only=True, source='logo.url')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
```

logo is an ImageField in the model. it must not be nullable in order to avoid errors like `ValueError: The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it.`

I only use `.build_absolute_uri` in a serializer methodfield to return absolute urls that use other views in my API. for example, in my project there is an URL `/webviews/projects/<pk>` that shows, a title and a button that collects some user input (i.e. not exactly what you would do with suffixes, as it's not a plain representation of the resource but includes some logic instead). the end point `/projects/<pk>/` contains a field "webview_url" ponting there, which is generated with SerializerMethodField. it's not media.

Answer (score 6):

No need for any overrides or customizations. DRF handles it automatically. Take a look at `to_representation` method of `FileField` ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/9e05aa59622fc3b859b7bc0b3abb81573a83bed7/rest_framework/fields.py#L1539)):

```
def to_representation(self, value):
    if not value:
        return None

    use_url = getattr(self, 'use_url', api_settings.UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL)

    if use_url:
        if not getattr(value, 'url', None):
            # If the file has not been saved it may not have a URL.
            return None
        url = value.url
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is not None:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(url)
        return url
    return value.name
```

Note that it won't work if the context of the serializer is not set properly. If you're using `ViewSet`s, no worries, everything is done silently but if you're instantiating the serializer manually you have to pass in the request in the context.

```
context = {'request': request}
serializer = ExampleSerializer(instance, context=context)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#file-fields-as-urls

Comment: The important bit here is to use FileField (not URLField) and add the request to the context.

Comment: got issue with ListAPIView and your solution with context is working! thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the context and pass request object. if you are using @api_view

```
serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, context={"request": request})
```

For ViewSet user get_serializer_context method

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Project.objects.all()
serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {'request': self.request}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass this   `"context={'request': request}"`  argument where you call your model serializer class to serialize the object. You can follow the below snippet to get the complete URL field.

```
serialized_object = serializers.MySerializer(data, many=true, context={'request': request})
```

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot access extra context in your serializer using Viewsets, try register your router with a basename in urls.py:

```html
router.register('projects', ProjectViewSet, basename='project')
```

you can use build_absolute_uri:

```html
def get_thumbnail_url(self, obj):
    return self.context.get('request').build_absolute_uri(obj.thumbnail.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you settings.py

media settings.

I had same error and found that:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
did the trick.

Before i only had:

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, override to_representation method works right.

```
# models.py
class DailyLove(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pic = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/api/media/DailyLove/')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

# serializers.py
class DailyLoveSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(DailyLoveSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['pic_url'] = self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri('/' + instance.pic.url)
        return representation

    class Meta:
        model = DailyLove
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
class DailyLoveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DailyLove.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = DailyLoveSerializer

# result
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8088/daily/3/",
        "date": "2019-05-04T12:33:00+08:00",
        "content": "123",
        "pic": "http://localhost:8088/daily/upload/api/media/DailyLove/nitish-meena-37745-unsplash.jpg",
        "pic_url": "http://localhost:8088/upload/api/media/DailyLove/nitish-meena-37745-unsplash.jpg"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

check this!

```
class FileFieldWithLinkRepresentation(serializers.FileField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return create_link(value.url, self.context['request'])
```

and `create_link` method:

```
def create_link(path: str, request: Request):
    domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    if not path.startswith('/', 0, 1):
        path = '/' + path
    return request.scheme + "://" + domain + path
```

you can use `FileFieldWithLinkRepresentation` in every class that needs hyperlink 
representation of a `FileField`.