# Django, REST framework - How to ensure absolute url will be returned for image?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-imagekit

I need viewset to return always absolute url for avatar / avatar_thumbnail image fields in response, but I'm getting relative paths. I have two such cases: 1st) is in image field in nested serializer, 2nd) is in viewset where I want to use two serializers in retrieve method.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
  avatar = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='users/',format='JPEG',options={'quality': 60})
  avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',processors=[ResizeToFill(50, 50)],format='JPEG')
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)here
```

forum/api/serializers.py *(nested serializer)*

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar_thumbnail = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'avatar_thumbnail']

class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'subject', 'user']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['user'] = UserSerializer(instance.user).data
        return representation
```

forum/api/views.py

```
class ThreadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer
    queryset = Thread.objects.all()
```

For UserViewSet I have also similar problem with urls for "avatar". I need absolute urls. I get relative url, but only when I overwrite retrieve method in viewset. (I overwrite it to use different serializer "UserPrivateSerializer" for user that is owner of the profile) .For list I always get absolute url.

users/api/serializers.py

```
class UserPublicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['id', 'username', 'avatar']

class UserPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'avatar']
```

users/api/views.py 
    *(Here the problem is with additional serializer, that I want to use in retrieve method)*

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.exclude(username='user_deleted')
    serializer_class = UserPublicSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Custom retrieve method use UserPrivateSerializer if the user object is requested by it's owner.
    """
    super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    instance = self.get_object()
    if request.user == instance:
        serializer = UserPrivateSerializer(instance)
    else:
        serializer = UserPublicSerializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found out that the problem is solved when I add context to serializers.

forum/api/serializers.py

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'subject', 'user']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['user'] = UserSerializer(instance.user, context=self.context).data
        return representation
```

users/api/views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.exclude(username='user_deleted')
    serializer_class = UserPublicSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        instance = self.get_object()
        if request.user == instance:
            serializer = UserPrivateSerializer(instance, context={'request': request})
        else:
            serializer = UserPublicSerializer(instance, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have found my answer here: [Django REST Framework and FileField absolute url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918619/django-rest-framework-and-filefield-absolute-url)
*"The request must available to the serializer, so it can build the full absolute URL for you. One way is to explicitly pass it in when the serializer is created"*